# Prime in sequences

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I would like to type prime above n in phrases:

```
a_n\prime
```

but I need help. Prime is next to a_n. I'm using: `\usepackage{amsmath}` and I should expect this as in the image that I have attached.

[image]

Comment: If I understand well, a simple `a_{n'}` should do what you want.

Comment: Even simpler: I think `a'_n` is what you want.

Comment: @JouleV it's not a solution, becouse the first is prime and second n, but I would have prime and n in one "column"

Comment: Maybe this is caused by the font metrics (this clearly isn't CM). Or something like `$a_{\mathkern-2mu n}'$`.

Comment: you should almost never use `\prime` `\prime` is a full size prime only ever intended to be used in superscripts so `^{\prime}` but just using `'` is the same as using `^{\prime}` In what way do you want the output from `a'_n` to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing `$a_n\prime$` is a mistake. You should write either `$a_n^{\prime}$`, `$a_n'$`, or `$a'_n$`. (I prefer the 2nd and 3rd options...)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$a_n\prime$ $a_n^{\prime}$ $a_n'$ $a'_n$
\end{document}
```